# How to use itertools combinations/permutations to stop only halfway through the list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a project in school where we are going to brute force a password, and we have gotten a list of passwords. The password is a combination of two words on the list, so we have to make this list ourselves.

I have tried this, using itertools:

```
    list_of_letters = open("passwords.txt").readlines()
    for word in itertools.permutations(list_of_letters):
        print(''.join(word))
```

But I get a file of 18,9 GB, and even that wasn't enough, due to me not having any more space on my device, as it will need space for 1 mill passwords. Therefore I need to split up this into several files, preferably like 3GB each. How can I do this, and still get all of the combination? I was thinking of dividing the original password-file, but then I will not get all of the combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) you will find this:

> If r is not specified or is None, then r defaults to the length of the iterable and all possible full-length permutations are generated.

Since you did not specify `r` this means `itertools.permutations` will generate all permutations with the length(line count) of your `password.txt`.
What you want is to specify `r` and set it to `2`, to only get permutations with a length of 2:

```
itertools.permutations(list_of_letters, 2)
```

---

In addition, using `.readlines()` will lead to all strings having newlines so your "password" will have a newline in the middle so thats a bug you might want to fix too.

The full code for this could look like this:

```
import itertools

# Use a context manager to ensure the file is closed once we're done
with open("passwords.txt") as f:
    # Strip off the `\n` at the end of each line
    list_of_letters = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    for word in itertools.permutations(list_of_letters, 2):
        print(''.join(word))
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful :) I see that my list turns out like this:

123456
password

123456
qwerty

and not:

123456password
123456qwerty.

Do you know a possible way to solve this?

Comment: This is probably caused by `.readlines()`, use a list comprehension to strip the newlines, I updated my answer.